# Error in installing theme in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

I get the following error while installing a theme in Drupal 7 by URL input at theme install form :

```
Failed to connect to the server. The server reports the following message:
Cannot connect to FTP Server, check settings

For more help installing or updating code on your server, see the handbook.
```

What might be the problem?
Where am I going wrong?
Installing theme by downloading and putting it into sites/all/themes everytime is annoying.

Answer (score 1):

The following code worked for me,

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data -R /var/www/drupal(or your drupal web root name)/sites
```